# Reducing size of some entries in a table

Tags: tables, positioning, fontsize

In the epsilon column, how can I make the entries formed by four digits after the point take the same space as the entries formed by three digits?
[image]

EDIT:
Assume 0.015 is n centimeters/inches wide.
With

> ...take the same space as the entries formed by three digits?

I meant, how can I make a number like 0.0222 occupy no more than n centimeters/inches?

EDIT 2:
I wanted to do so because the extra digits were causing a table on the side of this one to be put under.

Comment: Please clarify what "make the entries formed by four digits after the point take the same space as the entries formed by three digits" is supposed to mean. E.g., do you want to *round* the numbers with four decimal digits to show just three decimal digits? Or, do you want to *truncate*, i.e., omit, the fourth decimal digit? Please be specific.

Comment: possibly padding the 3 digits

Comment: @Mico I wanted to make 0.0125 the same width of 0.015

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have a look at the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package. It provides the column type `S` for aligning numbers in a table. Please have a look into the package documentation for questions on grouping etc.

I propose the following solution:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setmainfont[Numbers={Monospaced}]{SourceSerifPro}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{A table with some numbers.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{
    S[table-format = 1.2]
    S[table-format = 2.1]
    S[table-format = 1.4]
    S[table-format = 1.7]
    S[table-format = 1.7]
}
\toprule
{\(\gamma\)} & {\(C\)} & {\(\epsilon\)} & {TR error} & {VS error}\\ \midrule
0.09 & 20 & 0.01 & 0.5158379 & 1.1113319\\
0.09 & 20 & 0.0175 & 0.0007536 & 1.1128601\\
0.1 & 17.5 & 0.02 & 0.4906799 & 1.1131233\\
0.1 & 25 & 0.015 & 0.4372142 & 1.1151788\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

the result:

[image: A table with some numbers using siunitx]

You can see that I did two more things:

- please use [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for creating beautiful tables
- some fonts like [Source Serif Pro](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-serif-pro) provide monospaced numbers that can be used in tables. Of course for otf or ttf fonts you have to compile your document using e.g. lualatex.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what is your problem, also you didn't provide any information about your document class, page layout etc. For now we only know, that you like to have two `tabular` environments in parallel.

With similar approach as in @Sebastian answer (+1), your tables can be formatted as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{ S[table-format=1.2]
                    S[table-format=2.1]
                    S[table-format=1.4]}
    \toprule
{$\gamma$} & {$C$} & {$\epsilon$}   \\
    \midrule
0.09 & 20   & 0.01      \\
0.09 & 20   & 0.0125    \\
0.09 & 22.5 & 0.015      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ S[table-format=1.7]
                    S[table-format=1.7]}    
    \toprule
{TR error} & {VS error} \\
    \midrule
0.5158379 & 1.1113319   \\
0.0007536 & 1.1128601   \\
0.0008913 & 1.1130204   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

If you like to have tables tied  connected, than put after first table `\end{tabular}` symbol `%`.

In the case, that you have two column document,than for your tables is still enough space in one column:

[image]

**Edit:**
Apparently you like to compress the width of letters of the longer number that it will have the same width of the shorter one. This demand can be done with reducing font size or use different fonts which narrower letters size for this particular number. Considering the first possibility, you can obtain with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{ S[table-format=1.2]
                    S[table-format=2.1]
                    S[table-format=1.4]}
    \toprule
{$\gamma$} & {$C$} & {$\epsilon$}   \\
    \midrule
0.09 & 20   & 0.01      \\
0.09 & 20   &\footnotesize 0.0125    \\
0.09 & 22.5 & 0.015      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ S[table-format=1.7]
                    S[table-format=1.7]}
    \toprule
{TR error} & {VS error} \\
    \midrule
0.5158379 & 1.1113319   \\
0.0007536 & 1.1128601   \\
0.0008913 & 1.1130204   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]
It is not clear /to me) what should be benefit of such table formatting. Width of table? From above MWE you can see, that your table can be fit in column width without any problem. However, you can also easily shrink it width with reducing `\tabcolsep`, i.e. size between columns content cells borders. For example with

```
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
```

from default value of 6 pt to 4 pt, which resulted gives `5 x 2 x 2pt = 20 pt` narrower table.

I encourage you to think again about what your table should look like.

Comment: Very kind Zarko... I have seen now....the user is Sebastian :-)))) and my name is Sebastiano. :-))))

Comment: @Sebastiano, oh I need a new glasses! Anyway, you usually write good  answers, so I mixed names :-). I will corrected names. Thank you very much for pointing to my error!

Comment: Don't worry ahahah :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've interpreted the stated objective

> make the entries formed by four digits after the point take the same space as the entries formed by three digits

as follows: "round the numbers to show (at most) 3 digits".

If this interpretation is correct, I suggest you employ the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type, since it can perform rounding to a pre-specified number of decimal digits.

Incidentally, I would align the numbers in all five data columns on their respective (explicit or implicit) decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,array}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\sisetup{group-digits=false}

\begin{document}

Without rounding in the $\epsilon$ column:

\begin{tabular}{ | T{1.2} T{2.2} 
                   T{1.4} || 
                   T{1.7} | T{1.7} | }
{$\gamma$} & {$C$} & {$\epsilon$} & {TR error} & {VS error} \\
\hline
0.01 & 20   & 0.01   & 0.5158379 & 1.1113319 \\
0.09 & 17.5 & 0.0125 & 0.5399814 & 1.1150787 \\
0.1  & 25   & 0.015  & 0.4372142 & 1.1151788 \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
With rounding to 3 decimal digits:

\begin{tabular}{ | T{1.2} T{2.2} 
                   T{1.3,round-mode=places,round-precision=3} || 
                   T{1.7} | T{1.7} | }
{$\gamma$} & {$C$} & {$\epsilon$} & {TR error} & {VS error} \\
\hline
0.01 & 20   & 0.01   & 0.5158379 & 1.1113319 \\
0.09 & 17.5 & 0.0125 & 0.5399814 & 1.1150787 \\
0.1  & 25   & 0.015  & 0.4372142 & 1.1151788 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't want to truncate/round the numbers. I wanted them to be aligned. e.g. possibly by shrinking the font of 0.0125

Comment: @GerardoZinno - They say that there's no arguing about tastes, but I must say that I find the plan to typeset numbers at potentially widely differing font sizes within one and the same column appalling, from a typographic point of view. Aside: Would you like me to delete this answer as it evidently doesn't meet your typesetting objective?

Comment: No, leave the answer! It may be useful to someone else. I know it is appalling, I was looking for any kind of solution, just suggested one lol. I had to submit an assignment  and I didn't have much time. That four-significant-digit numbers were screwing up the position of other nearby tables too. At the end of the day I replaced `0.abcd` with `.abcd`. @Mico

Answer (score 0):

**NB! If you load the code of your tabular in the question, it is much easier to advice you.**

I assume you want to align the column at the decimal point, and in that case, load [dcolumn](https://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) and use D{.}{.}{1.4}.

If you really want to squeeze four digits into the space of three, load [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array), and use a fixed width `w` column, `wc{25pt}`. You will receive some warnings regarding "overfull hbox".

In you preamble, load [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array):

```
\usepackage{array}
```

In you tabular preamble, use `wc{25pt}` instead of your definition of column 3. Increase or reduce the width of the column until the two tabulars fit. You can also reduce the space between columns:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
```

Possible MWEs:

**If it is one tabular:**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c c wc{20pt}||c c|}
$\gamma$ & $C$ & $\epsilon$ & TR error & VS error \\

\hline

0.09 & 20 & 0.01 & 0.5158379 & 1.1113319\\
0.09 & 20 & 0.0175 & 0.0007536 & 1.1128601\\ 


\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Or if there are two tabulars:**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c c wc{20pt}|}
$\gamma$ & $C$ & $\epsilon$ \\
\hline
0.09 & 20 & 0.01 \\
0.09 & 20 & 0.0175 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|c c|}
TR error & VS error \\
\hline
0.5158379 & 1.1113319\\
0.0007536 & 1.1128601\\ 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, I want them to take the same space so two tables will be side by side. The fact that column has a digit more makes another table go under.

Comment: @GerardoZinno - In your comment, you introduce a potentially very important new piece of information, *viz.*, that you're aiming to place two tables side by side. Is this fact truly important? If so, you should probably edit your query to mention this fact up front.